# Parse and Swift: Add comment to post through Array to a Object Using a Relation?

Tags: arrays, swift, post, parse-platform, comments

**I am new to swift and parse... I have tried reading through the documentation for Parse on how to make comments on a post and have seen the different ways but am confused.** 
For now, I have chosen to create an array because I don't believe there will be a lot of comments(for the time being).

So the way it is set up is I have class in parse known as "posts" in the class there is a column that is a string which is "post" and then another column that is an array that is "comments".

I have the "posts" being presented in a tableview and then when the user is prompted to another view controller(showing the post and the time it was posted) which has a comment button on the bottom that prompts a comment view controller modally.

**The postPressed function is adding the text to the comment array to a new row and not adding the text to the comment array in the row of the original post.**

```
  @IBAction func postPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var object = PFObject(className: "Post")
    object.addObject(self.commentView?.text, forKey: "comment")
    object.saveInBackground()
```

**Like I said, I tried reading the documentation and am confused on whether there should be a PFRelation or a PFQuery to relate the comment to the post.**

Comment: Hello! Were you able to fix this? I'm stuck in something similar

Comment: Hi, yes I was! I fixed it with prepareforsegue(the function for passing data)... I had code, but made a stupid mistake (so make sure everything is linked up together correctly). Here's a great tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw

Comment: Let me know if you still have issues!

Comment: Okay I'll look it up. Because I am trying to pass data that I am using on Parse.com and it wasn't doing it.

Comment: Okay So I tried what he did and the app crashed, and the error said:
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x38abe834) to 'yourApp.DetailViewContoller' (0x144ae8). So this line of code `var destViewController: DetailViewContoller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewContoller` is wrong. That's what he had on the view, and I tried other ways to do it and I still get errors, or the data is not passed

Comment: Okay so I managed to display the post in a different viewController so you can comment on it, but now I'm having trouble in adding comments to it.

Comment: Edit: I managed to saved the comments into the array in parse.com, so everything is set now. I'm just having trouble displaying the comments into the tableView so that they are visible to other users, but I can confirm that the comments are being saved in the array in parse.

Comment: That's good news! I'm glad you worked that out. So, to display the comments you would set up a tableview and a label and then use code like `var commentCell =tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourCommentColumn", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentTableView
        cell.commentLabel?.text = comments![indexPath.row]`

Comment: Okay I have that but it's not doing it. I also get an error. NSArray index out of bounds or something like that

Comment: I used those lines of code you posted into a function called 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' and the comments were not displayed. I know they are being added because I printed them and they show, but not on the tableView

Comment: Have you properly configured you tableview? That code I posted above has to be in a func like `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var aComment =tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourCommentColumn", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentTableView cell.commentLabel?.text = comments![indexPath.row] return cell } `

Comment: Yeah I did. I was missing the UITableViewDataSource at the top of the class. It works fine now!

Comment: Nice! Yeah, sometimes making a checklist to prevent missing the basic stuff can really help.

Comment: Yes. The app is looking good now. I'm implementing a like button, but I've been having trouble to make one like per user. I have it so that when you click like, you cannot click on it anymore, but if you close the app an open it again, it lets you click on 'like' again. But anyways, thanks for the help! I really appreciate it! A lot of times is hard to get someone to actually help you on here.

Comment: No problem. Yeah it can be hard to find someone on here sometimes... A  workaround to your problem is if your app has users you can build some sort of boolean value that a specific user has already disliked or liked that specific object. You would need the involvement of pointers and relational data types which parse has some good documentation on(I have tried working with that but definitely have had some trouble doing it successfully). The other issue with relational and pointer data is that sometimes it can increase the query limit set by Parse drastically.

Answer (score 0):

The array approach should work, though a relationship is likely better suited and more flexible for your future needs, like knowing who commented, how many times yhey commented, blah.

The problem is that by calling `var object = PFObject(className: "Post")` you're creating a new empty Post object and adding a single comment to it. You should actually be passing the post that the user selected into your comment view controller and updating that post instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How exactly should I pass the post that the user selected into the comment view controller and then what method would I use to update that specific post the user chose? Should I add a "var post: PFObject?" at the top of the comment view controller? I am sorry if these are elementary questions I am new to all of this.

Comment: yes, exactly like that. then use `post` instead of the `object` you are currently creating.

Comment: Hmm so I tried doing that with that code...      
    
"var question: PFObject?" and "@IBAction func postPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
         var post = PFObject(className: "Post")
         post.addObject(self.commentView?.text, forKey: "comment")
         post.saveInBackground()"    

It didn't seem to update anything on the backend.

Comment: you're still doing `var post = PFObject(className: "Post") ` which creates a new post. you need to get the post that was selected by the user and update it

Comment: Tried removing that as well... with only       post!.addObject(self.commentView?.text, forKey: "comment")
post!.saveInBackground()"     
    
Still did nothing on the backend

Comment: I had this PFRelation originally in the code, too... "var relation : PFRelation = post.relationForKey("post")" which was the reason that the text to the comment array to a new row and not adding the text to the comment array in the row of the original post. Sorry I ended up missing that I still had it.

Comment: what is 'postPressed' called by? How are you showing posts for a user to choose?

Comment: Post are being being presented in a tableview and then when the user selects a post they are prompted to another view controller(showing the post and the time it was posted(like a detail view controller)) which has a comment button on the bottom(of the detail view controller) that prompts a comment view controller modally. On the comment view controller is a two navigation buttons(post(postPressed) and cancel(cancelPressed)) and a text view(commentView) as the whole page.

Comment: This is the comment view controller code...                                            import UIKit

class CommentViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {  

    var post: PFObject?

    var comments: [String]?

    var reset:Bool = false

    @IBOutlet weak var commentView: UITextView!  

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()       

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

Comment: "@IBAction func cancelPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func postPressed(sender: AnyObject) {        

        post?.addObject(self.commentView?.text, forKey: "comments")

        post?.saveInBackground()

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)

    }  

  func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

        if(reset == false){

        self.commentView.text = String(Array(self.commentView.text)[0])

        reset = true

    }

}

}

Comment: So, you have an array or similar to populate the table view. When a cell is selected, get the post from the array and pass it to the second view controller.

Comment: Yes I have a column called "posts" of type string that will populate the table view. It goes to a detail view controller and then in that detail view controller there is a button that leads another view controller called comment view controller. I was able to pass the post successfully from the table view to the detail view controller but when I try the same techniques with the comment view controller I am having trouble successfully doing it.

Comment: So I am confused on how to programmatically pass the specific post from the table view to comment view controller and adding the text to the array of comments that belongs to that specific post.